# Pass html innerHTML into a javascript object

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to update my hotel star rating based on the updated id="messasge-13" that gets generated

Within message-13, will appear a value either; 1,2,3,4 or 5 depending on the hotel on buttonclick

Before any  query has been made, it will show 0 stars

I have tried wrapping the script contents into a function that gets called on button click, but that did not work either.

Here is the core code:

```
<p id="message-13"></p>

<script>
    const ratings = {
      hotel_a : 0
    }
    var hotel_a = parseInt(document.getElementById("message-13").innerHTML,10);
     // total number of stars

    const starTotal = 5;
      for(const rating in ratings) {  
        const starPercentage = (ratings[rating] / starTotal) * 100;
        const starPercentageRounded = `${(Math.round(starPercentage / 10) * 10)}%`;
        document.querySelector(`.${rating} .stars-inner`).style.width = starPercentageRounded; 
      }
</script>
```

Once a query has been made, I want to pass the value from message-13 into the key: hotel_a

However, I am unable to update the hotel_a value

The search button:

```
    <form>
        <input placeholder="Search here">
           <button>Search</button>
    </form>
```

The search then calls an api to retrieve JSON parsed data of which includes the hotel rating. This is in the form of id=message-13 which returns the value 1 to 5

I have another javascript which fetches the data from a long url:

```
        const messageThirteen = document.querySelector('#message-13')
        const messageFourteen = document.querySelector('#message-14')


        fetch('http://localhost:3000/search?address='+location+'&checkin='+checkindate+'&checkout='+checkoutdate).then((response) => {


    response.json().then((data) => {
         if (data.error) {
                messageThirteen.textContent = ''
                messageFourteen.textContent = ''
        } else {
                messageThirteen.textContent = data.hotelStar
                messageFourteen.textContent = data.hotelRating
```

Comment: Where is the button and what decides the rating?

Comment: can you post the entire code in the question so we could understand the question better

Comment: Added more of the code

Comment: What do you see when you debug? Do you get an error when trying to update `hotel_a`? Where is the code that tries to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you get the ratings but you can use the method below to get the value passed to `hotel_a`.
If the value is already passed in `document.querySelector('#message-13').innerHTML;` Just remove `rating_paragraph = 5;`

```js
const ratings = {
      hotel_a : 0
    }

const button = document.querySelector('#search');
let rating_paragraph = document.querySelector('#message-13').innerHTML;

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
rating_paragraph = 5; //Assign your api call hotel value here as rating_paragragh

ratings.hotel_a = rating_paragraph;
console.log(ratings.hotel_a)
})
```

```html
<p id="message-13"></p>

<button id="search">Search</button>
```